# CSS popup doesn't carry PHP variable

Tags: php, css

I'm building a website with a CSS popup inside a loop that increments by 1, but the variable $i does not carry on the popup.

**CSS**

```
#cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
#score {
    height: 380px;
    min-width: 280px;
    max-width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    background: url(login.png) no-repeat;
    border: 5px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#score:target,
#score:target + #cover {
    display: block;
    opacity: 2;
}
.cancel {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 2px;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    color: black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 35px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
}
.popup .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php $loopvalue = 3; $i=1; while ($i <= $loopvalue) {?>
<li><a href="#score">open popup <?php echo $i;?></a></li>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="score" style="background-color:#FFF;">
            popup # <?php echo $i;?> 
            <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
        </div>
    <div id="cover" >
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The popup number $i never changes. It freezes on 1. I'm not sure what's the problem. I don't see any, but I can't make the popup number change.

Comment: from where you are getting the value of $i ?

Comment: from my loop <?php $war_size = $_GET['war_size']; $loopvalue = $war_size; $i=1; while ($i <= $loopvalue) { ?>

Comment: could you please check whether you are incrementing the $i inside while loop

Comment: just clean my post with all the needed code  but after the class popup btw is position:fixed; the loop dont work

Comment: Just ran this locally and not having any issue.

Comment: You want the id on div ? It's working fine <div id="score<?php echo $i?>" style="background-color:#FFF;">
test increment <?php echo $i;?>

        </div>

Comment: i cant make it work i just add the css but can not make the $i change inside a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codes you have repeated the score div with same id. it need to have different ids for different divs

(This will only create proper html. for popup effect it needs to use some java script/JQuery codes)

Try this

```
<?php $loopvalue = 3; $i=1; while ($i <= $loopvalue) {?>
  <li><a href="#score<?php echo $i;?>">open popup <?php echo $i;?></a></li>
  <div class="popup">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="score<?php echo $i;?>" style="background-color:#FFF;">
            popup # <?php echo $i;?> 
            <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
        </div>
        <div id="cover" > </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
<?php $i++;}?>
```

Comment: it only give me a hounded of results but the popup dont open

Comment: really that work for you ??'  its not working on my end 
using wamp
Apache Version :    2.4.9  
PHP Version :    5.5.12  
MySQL Version :
    5.6.17

Comment: This don't popup anything. but it creates the correct html markup. you need to have some java script to really popup the div.